# Is causality perpetual?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics, causation

Suppose causality were not perpetual, then at some point, it must have been created.

Then there was a process that constructed it, i.e. a causal process. But we assumed absence of any causality. Contradiction.

Thus all predicates that define causality are uniquely specified and axiomatic.

At least, that's how it seems, initially.

Comment: Causality is a rule, and rules exist only in our heads. So, causality is as perpetual as each one's individual existence.

Comment: @RodolfoAP -- or causality could be the fundamental property the reality we live in. It exists in our heads as one of the ideas we form about the world we live in.

Comment: @YuriZavorotny Kant spent his whole career attempting to demonstrate that there's in fact no difference. And I think we can safely say, 200 years after, that there is no difference.

Comment: @abcga -- are you saying there is no such thing as the world outside of your mind? That the chair you are sitting on is a figment of your imagination? That may well be true, mind you, but I don't think you can safely say that this is the only possibility.

Comment: I think what Kant was trying to say is that our ideas of the world are meant to reflect that world as a perfect mirror. Still, a reflection, even if it captures every detail and is not distorted in any way, is not the same as the real thing.

Comment: Have a look at Conformal Cyclic Cosmology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology in which when there are only photons left, time ceases & the universe becomes conformally equivalent to a Big Bang. The standard view in cosmology is that time began at the Big Bang. How can causality be meaningful without time?

Answer (score 1):

If causality is understood as a *necessary connection*, then indeed it is "perpetual" (although that's an odd way to put it) in the sense that it applies to all possible worlds (and all possible moments in time, there isn't a significant difference).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether causality only exists in our heads.

Nevertheless, causality is a heuristic principle or possibly even a law of nature. Heuristics and laws of nature are not created like physical particles.

Comment: Causality (a.k.a. determinism) is a scientific theory. As such, we assume it is true for as long as it corresponds to observations and experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Causality is a mere assumption. Just like everything else we think we know about the world outside our minds -- mere assumptions. We must make those assumptions in order to function, and we do, if only implicitly.

Now, those assumptions are about the world that is, and we are just as free to make them even when we have no idea of how this world came to be (e.g. whether it always existed in some form, or was created out of nothing some 14 billion years ago, or 10 seconds ago along with our memories).

What matters, I think, is that we can *speculate* about this world being fundamentally casual/deterministic, and assume that it is, in fact, so for as long as this theory is confirmed through experiments and observations.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the second premise. "Then there was a process that constructed it", this isnt immediately necessary, and this is evident once u check the notion of brute facts. Although a beginning would be necessary, the beginning could simply lack an explanans and thus be a brute fact, occuring for no reason. But this is only a hypothetical possibility, as i do believe in the PSR and so i do think that the assumption is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Physical phenomena such as radioactive decay do not depend on causality. If you had four apples on a shelf and one went bad, then we might attribute this to it having been bruised - having some invisible damage. If we had four radioactive atoms and one decayed, the current belief is that any of them were equally likely to do this at any moment, and there is no internal 'memory' of age or accumulated damage.

The vacuum is filled with virtual particles. Electron-positron pairs continuously pop into existence, and then annihilate themselves without disturbing the energy budget. We can detect these via phenomena such as elec iron-positron creation from gamma rays, or the Casmir force. The appearance of causality is a property of macroscopic things, which are composed of many atomic and subatomic things that do not obey causality.

We see the progression of things as an increase in entropy. Time is symmetric in many physics equations, but 'forward' in time is the direction in which things 'run down', 'degrade', or increase in entropy as a whole.

It is perfectly reasonable to believe on experimental evidence that causality is not obeyed at the microscopic scale. By extension, it is reasonable for the whole universe to pop into existence without cause. Once created, the overall entropy of the universe is statistically bound to increase, which makes it likely to expand forever, and very hard to get it all back into the point where it came from. This also accords with what astronomers now tell us. The astronomer Fred Hoyle had a 'steady state' theory that heat that the universe had always existed, and low entropy matter spontaneously came into existence, but this does not fit with what we see.

So..

We are not required to believe in an infinite staircase of cause and effect. We are not even required to assume the first step where something else creates our universe. The universe may have some creating cause, but we are not required to believe this. If it does, and the laws in this 'universe of creators' are recognisable to us, then it will also run towards increasing entropy, and will 'run down' with their time. If it does not, then it is something wholly outside our experience. It is interesting to speculate and list the options, but without some kind of testable theory it currently gets us nowhere.